# Create a relationship between two attributes in LDAP

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I created two attributes in LDAP (multivalued strings) and I want to (somehow) create a relationship between their values so that each value in one of then is linked to a value in the second:
for example the attributes are 'cars' and 'owners'

```
car name - owner name
BMW   ->   john doe1
KIA   ->   john doe2
.
.
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

**Edit**:
can I use the freeipa plugins to modify the user input so that it appends a value from the second attribute to the first attribute?

```
BMW(john doe1)
KIA(john doe2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about LDAP is not a Relationship Database but a plain directory. What you can do is create a group for the cars and add to this group the users who have this car.

Something like:

```
dn: cn=BMW,ou=cars,dc=yourcompany,dc=com
cn: BMW
objectclass: posixgroup
memberuid: john
memberuid: alex

dn: cn=KIA,ou=cars,dc=yourcompany,dc=com
cn: KIA
objectclass: posixgroup
memberuid: tara
memberuid: gina
memberuid: peter
```

Comment: +1. One important note - LDAP does not guarantee order of the values for the multivalued string. So the original proposal would never work.

Answer (score 0):

I found these pages while searching for answers which exactly what I was looking for:
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Advanced_Entry_Management-Assigning_Class_of_Service.html

[https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.2/html/Administration_Guide/Advanced_Entry_Management-Assigning_Class_of_Service.html](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Advanced_Entry_Management-Assigning_Class_of_Service.html)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4809/6ng8g55ib/index.html

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4811/fnysm/index.html